# Link against two static libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

I am working on a very large project that has several Visual Studio projects. These projects are built as static libraries and included in the Main project, let's call it `Main.exe`.

I have created a new project and built it as a static library, let's call it `MyProj.lib`. This library is dependent upon another static library, let's call it `API.lib`.

Now, I need to link my project to the Main project. Currently I have both of the static libraries linked to the Main project. I previously asked this question: [Link static library in another static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198261/include-static-library-in-static-library) and found out that I can't nest the static libraries. Paul Michalik pointed out that I need to simply link the two libraries independently when I build the Main project.

I now get several `LNK2019` errors from the `MyProj.lib` library, saying that it can't find the symbols that are defined in the `API.lib` library. Visual Studio knows where both of the library files are, so this is very confusing to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of confusion stems from the mistaken believe that .lib files are somehow magical.  That a linker could *see* that a .lib file has other dependencies.  That is just not the case, a static .lib is just a bag of .obj files.  A way to collect compiler output into a single file.  Nothing more, nothing less.

What is especially confusing about it is that when you *build* the library, it will never complain about missing dependencies.  The explanation for that is simple, building a library does *not* run the linker.  Just the lib.exe tool that collects the .obj files into a bag.

It doesn't come together until you actually run the linker to build the final executable.  Now all the pieces have to come together, the linker *has* to also see the .obj or .lib file that contains the dependencies.  It complains when it doesn't.

That's a very weak link in the C/C++ build model, hard to fix.  Vendors have tried to address this, Microsoft did too.  They added the non-standard #pragma comment(lib, "something.lib") feature to tell the linker that it needs to link "something.iib" without you explicitly specifying it in the linker's Additional Dependencies setting.  Very nice.  Dealing with exactly *where* "something.lib" is stored is however a problem you need to deal with.  Crud.  Another setting.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to simply add the `.lib` files to each of the projects which rely on them.  In case it matters (it probably does not for VS), place the depended-upon library before the depending-on library.

The (possible) disadvantage of this is that the libraries are not recompiled automatically when they change.

Comment: Are you saying link  `API.lib` to `MyProj.lib` and link both in the Main project? I have tried that and it gives me about 3600+ linker warnings.

Comment: @Derek:  That would happen if MyProj.lib *contains* API.lib.  But MyProj should only contain external references to API and whatever else, not the modules and symbols referenced.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow you. Right now `MyProj.lib` is being built as a library without linking to `API.lib`.